# Why does my UITableView report itself as 600x600, or what it is in the Storyboard, when I have constraints set?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, ios8

My `UITableView`, when I `po` the frame in the debugger, reports its width and height as 600x600. I have it pinned to the sides of its view controller, so I don't understand why it would be reporting this.

The 600x600 is its dimensions within the `Any` x `Any` Storyboard grid, but like I said, it should be updating.

Is this a glitch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will report 600x600 dimensions until its layout is complete. If you override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method and put a breakpoint there:

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
   [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
   //
   // NSLog frame here
}
```

You will get proper frame size.

Comment: But this is where I set up some views, and as viewDidLayoutSubviews can be called multiple times, it adds them all.

Comment: That's entirely different question :) You should not setup your view hierarchy inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` precisely for the reason - it will be called multiple times.

Comment: Any hints as so where I should set it up in? For now I'm just setting a flag if the views are set up.